# Does importing a "non-relevant" dll has a performance penalty?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, import

I'm using c#. In many cases I'm writing code that can benefit from a very simple class/method located in a "non-relevant" dll. For example, I'm writing some algorithm with no UI but it can benefit from a Point class in System.Drawing, or I need some xml manipulation method from System.Web even though I'm writing a console app (these are just examples).

Besides the "code smell" - is there a performance penalty for importing a big assembly for a small chunk of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a performance penalty associated with loading assemblies (e.g. loading assemblies require verification and occupies address space from your process), but **it may not be significant**, so you should check how it affects your application. Most likely it will not be a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The size of the assembly does not matter, so it's just 1 DLL extra. You probably already have between 10 and 30, and loading 1 extra is very cheap.